# Por quanto tempo uma pergunta fica armazenada?

Tags: suporte

Existe um prazo para uma pergunta permanecer no site? Posso esperar que uma pergunta com um número positivo de votos estará sempre disponível?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não existe garantia de que a pergunta esteja sempre disponível, embora na maioria dos casos ela seja de fato armazenada indefinidamente. Mesmo se a pergunta for deletada, ela continua na base de dados (é um *soft delete*, a exclusão somente marca um flag no banco de dados), e é acessível por quem possui o privilégio de "acesso às ferramentas de moderação", contanto que tenha o link da pergunta. Em casos bastante raros (solicitação de remoção de conteúdo devido a alguma questão legal), uma postagem pode ser excluída definitivamente do banco (*hard deleted*).

O fato de a pergunta possuir muitos votos não garante que ela permaneça no site. Caso no futuro as regras do site mudem, uma pergunta popular pode acabar sendo fechada ou mesmo excluída. Além disso, perguntas sem respostas acabam excluídas automaticamente após algum tempo (1 ano, acho).

Portanto: se você quer ter certeza absoluta de que não perderá determinado conteúdo, mantenha uma cópia local do mesmo.

Comment: Acabei de verificar uma pergunta que eu fiz em janeiro do ano passado no SO.com e não tinha nenhuma resposta nem comentário, e ela foi excluída no dia 1º de fevereiro desse ano por Community♦, não sabia que isso acontecia, achei que elas ficavam por tempo indeterminado. Obrigado pela informação.

Answer (score 5):

Até onde eu sei as perguntas são armazenadas para sempre. Tanto que se pede para evitar links para outros sites (sendo que não se tem domínio sobre o tempo de armazenamento de outros).

Comment: Acabei de perceber que não sou capaz de marcar qual é a resposta correta.

Comment: Isso vale também para perguntas deletadas. Elas continuam disponíveis para quem tem o link e privilégios suficientes.